# In an autocmd what's the use of the BufRead event?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, buffers, autocmd, filetype

I'm trying to learn a bit of vimscript and currently reading [the 12th chapter](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html) of Learn Vimscript the Hard Way.

In this page, the author says :

> A common idiom in Vim scripting is to pair the BufRead and BufNewFile
>   events together to run a command whenever you open a certain kind of
>   file, regardless of whether it happens to exist already or not.

So I thought I would try this for a problem I have.
I've got a folder in which I would like to be sure all files have the filetype markdown.
The folder contains existing files, which have the filetype text and don't have any extension.

I added the following line to my vimrc :

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /path/to/my/folder/* set filetype=markdown
```

Now, when I create a new file inside my folder, the filetype is automatically set to markdown.
So the BufNewFile event is triggered as expected.
However, when I open an existing file, the filetype remains text, as if the BufRead event was not triggered.

I found two solutions :

1. delete the content of `~/.vim/view`
2. change the event to watch from `BufNewFile`,`BufRead` to `BufEnter`.

But out of curiosity I would like to understand a few things:

1. Why is the `BufRead` event not working ?
2. What's the difference between `BufRead` and `BufEnter` ?
3. For each file previously edited in vim, the `~/.vim/view` folder seems to have a corresponding file which stores its settings (filetype, indentation...). The settings stored in that file seem to have priority over an autocmd triggered by the `BufRead` event.
   So, what's the purpose of this event if it's unable to bypass what's inside the `view/` folder ?
4. If I want to be sure to automatically change any setting for a file with an autocommand, is the `BufEnter` event the right one to choose ?

Comment: How are views configured in your vimrc? The way it is described it appears to be set to automatically create these view files, as opposed to invoking `:mkview` manually? If possible I would like to reproduce what you're experiencing in order to look for an answer.

Comment: You're right, I completely forgot, I had those 2 lines inside my vimrc :

    `au BufWinLeave ?* mkview` and 
    `au BufWinEnter ?* silent loadview`

I suppose it was to automatically save and restore folds.

Comment: I had my suspicions, glad to hear my hint was of any use! I posted an answer as well, so this question can be marked as solved if you consider it so.

Comment: I marked the question as solved. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no precedence for views using `mkview` and `loadview` over buffer triggers such as `BufRead`. Whatever is executed last, will define which configuration is to be used.

Per discussed in the comments, there are two possible solutions to this question:

- Remove the `BufWinLeave` and `BufWinEnter` autocommands which make and load views.
- Or place the `BufRead` etc. commands after the view commands.